# Show script 1 from 6am to 12am and the rest of the time script 2

Tags: php, javascript, time, timezone

I have two Javascript but I want to display one from 6am to 12am (servertime not usertime) and the rest of the time script two

How would this be done?

An example on http://jsfiddle.net would be greatly appreciated

Comment: By `12am` can I just clarify whether you mean noon, or midnight?

Comment: well, what have you tried so far? Also, this can't be done clientside.

Comment: You can create a PHP script which returns which script should be run, and call it using AJAX. Than, on AJAX success you can chek if(data == 1) run_script1(); else run_script2();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$least=mktime(6,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
$most=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("y"));//12am next day OR
  $most=mktime(12,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));//12pm
if (time()>=$least && time()<=$most){
    ?>
        <script ...1
    <?php
}else{?>
        <script ..2...
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please see my new Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467555/displaying-code-between-time-a-and-time-b-not-working/11467646#11467646

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I have to Javascript but I want to display 1 from 6am to 12am (servertime not usertime) and the rest of the time script 2

Here's a script that uses the Date object in JavaScript, the script is actually really simple, but has the downside that it doesn't get the time from the server, but from the client.

http://jsfiddle.net/45yd2/

For a method that uses server time, include the jQuery library, and create this script:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'url-returing-hour',
    success: function( data ) {
        var hour = parseInt( data );
        if( hour > 6 && hour < 12 ) {
            jQuery('#first').show( );
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#second').show( );
        }
    }
});
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php
echo date('G');
```

Comment: Oh, where to begin? You're using the wrong quotes, and you're placing the alerts in a selector for jQuery... Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/AbNLc/

Answer (score -1):

you first set Server time to Client

like this code

for MVC3 razor

```
  var serverTime = { year : @(DateTime.Now.Year) ; month : @(DateTime.Now.Month)  , day : @(DateTime.Now.Day) ; hour : @(DateTime.Now.Hour)  };
  // your coundition goes here like
  if(serverTime.hour >= 6 && serverTime.hour <= 12)
     alert('yep');
```