# Displaying code between time a and time b not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display #1 from 15:00 (3pm) to next day 4:00 (4am) and the rest of the time #2

but for some reason it is not working?!

Here is my code thanks for your help

```
<?php
$least=mktime(15,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
$most=mktime(28,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));//12pm
if (time()>=$least && time()<=$most){
    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">

alert("#1");

</script>
    <?php
}else{?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

alert("#2");

</script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: servertime right now: Fri Jul 13 02:19:22 PDT 2012

Comment: Why you think it don't work? I copy you code and it work correct. for debug try out a current time before check. (4 $now = strtotime("+3 hour");
  5 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now)."\n";
  6 if ( $now >= $least && $now <= $most){)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple:

```php
$now = date('H',time());
if ($now>=4 && $now<=15){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("#2");
    </script>
<?php
}else{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("#1");
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: and this means from 3pm to 4am #2 and the rest of the time #1 is shown?

Comment: Yes, you have for each day the same three time intervals repeating: 00-04 [1], 04-15 [2], 15-24/00 [1], and so it's simple.

Comment: Also you can make the [negation of the conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering):  `echo ($now<4 || $now>15) ? '#1':'#2';` to swap both branches.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cur_hour = date("H");
$beg_hour = "11";
$end_hour = "28";
if ($cur_hour <= 4)
        $cur_hour += 24;
if ($cur_hour >= $beg_hour && $cur_hour <= $end_hour)
        echo "#1";
else
        echo "#2";
if ($cur_hour > 24)
        $cur_hour -= 24;
echo "<br /><br />".$cur_hour;
```

Now it should do it correctly.

Comment: How can a number be bigger than 15 and smaller than 4 at the same time? You must be a wizard.

Comment: Hmm, good point. But there should be such manipulations according to that these numbers actually ar hours.

Comment: There are, but your way is not correct. The OP's method is actually already better, because he uses 28 (24+4) for the hours and uses time() functions to compare.

Comment: @Dow but why is my code not funktioning right or am I missing something

Comment: $least=mktime(15,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
$most=mktime(28,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));//12pm 
its not that you need to change date("m") to date("H")? And actually remove date("d") and date("y") because You dont need them?